# How to supply inputs for multiple prompts in one command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, heredoc

I have a shell script `plan.sh` which expects a user input `(a/b)` and then asks for another input `(y/n)`.

I want to run this in one line like `sh -a -y plan.sh` which doesn't work.

I tried this too

```
./plan.sh << END_OF_INPUT
a
y
END_OF_INPUT
```

which throws an error:
`/bin/bash: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'END_OF_INPUT')`

Is there a way to do this better?

Comment: I assume that you have a space or tab after the last `END_OF_INPUT` in your original code.

Comment: `./plan.sh <<<$'a\ny\n'`, if your shell is `bash` and not `sh`

Comment: `printf '%s\n' a y | ./plan.sh`, to work on _any_ POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: But your original code should work fine if the file _really_ contained only 100% precisely the content shown in the question. Seems very likely there's indentation or something else off; we need a [mre] that lets us cause the problem ourselves to be able to provide a certain explanation.

Comment: (And just to emphasize: `sh yourscript` forces your script to be run with `sh`, not bash; even if your operating system is one where `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, it still turns off some bash-only features when started under the `sh` name -- and many common operating systems, like Debian and Ubuntu, don't use bash for sh at all; so if you want to ask a question with the bash Stack Overflow tag, you should be running your code with _bash_, not with _sh_)

Comment: Another idea is changing `plan.sh` and add parameters for the two questions.

Comment: See [Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/4154375).